# Extraño error wrapDatabaseException al guardar en base de datos SQFLITE (¿relacionado con imágenes?)

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Estoy tratando de guardar en una base de datos de SQFLITE unas imágenes en Uint8List, lo cual tengo entendido que es posible.
Esta es la clase que representa el modelo de datos:

```
class VisualEvaluation
{
  int? id;
  int? idForm;

  String goodSilagePicturePath;
  Uint8List goodSilagePicture;

  String spoiledSilagePicturePath;
  Uint8List spoiledSilagePicture;

  String visualSpoilageInfo;

  bool finished;

  VisualEvaluation({
    this.id,
    this.idForm,

    required this.goodSilagePicturePath,
    required this.goodSilagePicture,

    required this.spoiledSilagePicturePath,
    required this.spoiledSilagePicture,

    required this.visualSpoilageInfo,
    required this.finished,

  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    return{
      "id":id,
      "idForm": idForm,
      "goodSilagePicturePath":goodSilagePicturePath,
      "goodSilagePicture":goodSilagePicture,
      "spoiledSilagePicturePath":spoiledSilagePicturePath,
      "spoiledSilagePicture": spoiledSilagePicture,
      "visualSpoilageInfo": visualSpoilageInfo,
      "finished": finished,
    };
  }
}
```

Este es el SQL que crea la tabla:

```
static const String createTableVisualEvaluationSQL=
      "CREATE TABLE VisualEvaluation (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
      "idForm INTEGER,"
      "goodSilagePicturePath TEXT,"
      "goodSilagePicture BLOB,"
      "spoiledSilagePicturePath TEXT,"
      "spoiledSilagePicture BLOB,"
      "visualSpoilageInfo TEXT,"
      "finished NUMERIC,"
      "FOREIGN KEY(idForm) REFERENCES Forms(id));";
```

Y este el método que utilizo para guardar:

```
  Future insertVisualEvaluation(VisualEvaluation ve) async
  {
    Database database = await _openDB();

    try{
      await database.insert("VisualEvaluation", ve.toMap());
    }
    on Exception catch (_, ex)
    {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(ex);
      }
    }

  }
```

Al intentar guardar me sale un error que, por más que trato de buscar, no logro entender su causa:

```
I/flutter (25882): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11:7)
I/flutter (25882): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (25882): #1      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawInsert.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:392:14)
I/flutter (25882): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (25882): #2      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
I/flutter (25882): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (25882): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart:344:14)
I/flutter (25882): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Es la primera vez que me sale algo así, así como también es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con imágenes en SQFLITE, con lo cual creo que el error podría estar relacionado con eso. Aunque según lo que he leído, es posible guardar UInt8List en un BLOB, pienso que a lo mejor me estoy dejando a medias alguna "conversión" o algo similar por así decirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Este error es realativo, al menos en la mayoría de los casos que me ha pasado, a las claves foráneas.

Si os sucede vigilad que estéis metiendo bien la clave foránea en vuestro objeto y SQL.